# Why doesn't this Google query work as I expect?

Tags: google-search

I expect this [Google query](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ripper234+-site%3aripper234.com#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=1&q=link%3aripper234.com%2Fp+-site%3Aripper234.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=ee5b8d49ec6ea034)

> -site:ripper234 link:ripper234.com/p

to return all links to my posts (pages starting with http://ripper234.com/p) that do not originate from my blog. This doesn't seem to be working. Any idea why?

Comment: The link doesn't match what you say you've entered. It's `http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ripper234+-site:ripper234.com#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=1&q=link:ripper234.com%2Fp+-site%3Aripper234.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=ee5b8d49ec6ea034`

Comment: @ChrisF - it's the same (only reversed)

Comment: The link you've quoted in the question is just`-site:ripper234 link:ripper234.com/p` - which is not the same even taking urlencoding into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`link` does not work like that. I don't think it even works properly.

You could try

`"ripper234.com/p" -site:ripper234.com`

or just add Google analytics